# I want to learn how to pose the model and make it look more saturated for game thumbnail

Tags: rendering

First, I am a newbie so I think I might break some forum rules.
I bought this taco model, it looks great and the color pop
[image]

When I open it, It look like this, I am asking on what setting should I changed so that it can look like the above picture

[image]

Comment: You need to start by adding some lights: https://youtu.be/RRilLLyyn1Y    https://youtu.be/RDbrOpnIY7Q

Comment: Ah thanks for the tutorial, I didn't know it exist